# Python odeint: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type)

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I'm trying to solve a differential equation with odeint and for certain outputs, I get the message: "Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type)."

I've run the function with full_output=1 and this is what I get:

```
    lsoda--  at current t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching tout     
      in above message,  i1 =       500
      in above message,  r1 =  0.1799966984891D+05
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
{'hu': array([ 0.00301005,  0.00082527,  0.00232656,  0.00026312,  0.04182098,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]),
 'imxer': -1,
 'leniw': 26,
 'lenrw': 116,
 'message': 'Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).',
 'mused': array([          2,           2,           2,           1,           2,
                 0, -1014454328,       32533,          48,           0], dtype=int32),
 'nfe': array([     513,      825,     1328,     2496,     3872,        0,
       27648176,        0,       48,        0], dtype=int32),
 'nje': array([         30,          59,         103,         183,         268,
             32533, -1129892592,       32533,          48,           0], dtype=int32),
 'nqu': array([          1,           1,           1,           2,           1,
                 0, -1014454328,       32533,          48,           0], dtype=int32),
 'nst': array([     184,      268,      401,      803,     1303,        0,
       27648176,        0,       48,        0], dtype=int32),
 'tcur': array([  3.60000104e+003,   7.20000056e+003,   1.08000006e+004,
         1.44000002e+004,   1.79996698e+004,   4.74303020e-322,
         0.00000000e+000,   6.90364637e-310,   6.90364883e-310,
         6.90364637e-310]),
 'tolsf': array([  6.90364882e-310,   6.90364882e-310,   6.90364882e-310,
         6.90364882e-310,   6.90364882e-310,   4.79243676e-322,
         1.87610085e-316,   6.90365099e-310,   6.90364141e-310,
         3.21142670e-322]),
 'tsw': array([  7.84480753e-003,   7.84480753e-003,   7.84480753e-003,
         1.43999973e+004,   1.44001827e+004,   1.36600614e-316,
         1.36600139e-316,   1.36600614e-316,   1.36600614e-316,
         1.36600139e-316])}
```

I have no idea what's wrong with the ODE that I am solving though. Here is its code:

```
def computeDiffEquations(state,t, m_coll_vals, m_load_vals):
#assign variables
Tout_coll = state[0]
T_tank = state[1:]
m_coll = valueAt(m_coll_vals, t)
m_load = valueAt(m_load_vals, t)

#calculate collector temperature
Tin_coll = T_tank[-1]
Tave_coll = (Tin_coll + Tout_coll) / 2.
eta = c_0 - c_1 * ((Tave_coll - T_amb) / (I_coll)) - c_2 * (math.pow(Tave_coll-T_amb, 2.) / (I_coll))
Tout_coll_dot = (eta * A_coll * I_coll - m_coll * c_p * (Tout_coll - Tin_coll)) / coll_cap

#calculate tank temperature
#build the Qcondution 
T_tank_minus1 = np.insert(T_tank, 0, T_tank[0])[:-1] 
T_tank_plus1 = np.insert(T_tank, len(T_tank), T_tank[-1])[1:] 
Q_cond = (th_cond * A_node  / L_node) * (T_tank_minus1 - 2. * T_tank + T_tank_plus1)

#build the Qflow
if m_coll >= m_load :
    Q_flow = c_p * ((m_coll - m_load) * T_tank_minus1 - (m_coll - m_load) * T_tank)
    Q_flow[0] = c_p * (m_coll * Tout_coll - (m_coll - m_load) * T_tank[0] - m_load * T_tank[0])
    Q_flow[-1] = c_p * ((m_coll - m_load) * T_tank_minus1[-1] + m_load * T_chiller_out - m_coll * T_tank[-1])
else:
    Q_flow = c_p * ((m_load - m_coll) * T_tank_plus1 - (m_load - m_coll) * T_tank)
    Q_flow[0] = c_p * (m_coll * Tout_coll + (m_load - m_coll) * T_tank_plus1[0] - m_load * T_tank[0])
    Q_flow[-1] = c_p * (- (m_load - m_coll) * T_tank[-1] + m_load * T_chiller_out - m_coll * T_tank[-1])

#build the Qloss        
Q_loss = U_loss * A_loss * (T_amb - T_tank)

#assemble the equations
T_tank_dot = (Q_loss + Q_cond + Q_flow) / (rho * c_p * V_node)

return np.concatenate((np.array([Tout_coll_dot]),T_tank_dot))
```

Any idea why I'm etting this error? Thanks in advance!